# How to get in java code, a generated output XML by Xform engine

Tags: java, integration, xforms

My Application is using XForms for view and XForms generate output XML containing the answer given by user. If we include the following line

```
<fr:xforms-inspector xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"/>
```

in the code we can see the generated output in the screen. So for username if user type `amit` it would also come with the generated XML.

I actually wanted to get this generated XML in my Java Class to save it in database and parse it and split its contents. I have tried the following code for getting that XML but not able to get the generated XML.

```
BufferedReader requestData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;
try{
  while ((line = requestData.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line);
  }
} catch (Exception e){}
   return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Please let me know what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'd like to have Java code inside a servlet or JSP that receives XML posted to the servlet or JSP through an XForms submission, then I would recommend you parse it using an XML parser rather than doing this by hand. Doing this with Dom4j is quite simple; for instance to get the content of the root element (assuming that all you receive is an element with some text in it):

```
Document queryDocument = xmlReader.read(request.getInputStream());
String query = queryDocument.getRootElement().getStringValue();
```

And for reference, see the [full source](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/examples-jsp/flickr-search/service-search.jsp) of an example this is taken from.